# How in grails yml config access to environment variables?

Tags: grails, yaml, openshift

I want to use Openshift to host my Grails application, and setup MySQL database on Openshift.

Openshift provide only login and password for database, but connection string is in form of environment variables `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT` and I do not see what is actual values for this vars for my database. Now I need to setup my YML config to access database, but I need somehow access from YML to environment variables `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL*`.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can access just try using below code in your gsp page
System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME')

Comment: @AnantKolvankar it is not gsp page. I need to access in YML file. Please, read a question.

Comment: You want to read database config from your Openshift app right?

Comment: You can set your data source 
`production {
   dataSource {
      String host = System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST')
      String port = System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')
      String dbName = System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME')
      url = "jdbc:mysql://$host:$port/$dbName"
      username = System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME')
      password = System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD')

 
   }
}`

Comment: No, I have config in YML format, no grails code. I want in my YML config acces environment variables.

Comment: So in your current running application on openshift you can try using below code to access environment variables 
`System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST') `

Answer (score 8):

You reference the system environment variable with the name `MYVAR` via `${MYVAR}` in your yaml file.

> The values in `application.properties` are filtered through the existing
>   `Environment` when they are used, so you can refer back to previously
>   defined values (for example, from System properties).
>
> `app.name=MyApp 
>   app.description=${app.name} is a Spring Boot application`

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties

Comment: The current doc link is: [2.3.7. Property Placeholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties)